# How am i supposed to draw colored rectangles

Tags: winapi, draw

The rectangles are supposed to be randomly colored when I draw them with the left button. They have to be filled with color not only the border
I have tried to use pens and brushes but it doesn't work. I think that it is because of the method I am using to draw them. But I don't know how to do it otherwise.
Here is my code:

```
POINT LeftButtonDown;
POINT ptCurrent;
POINT ptClicked;
vector<CRect> vRect;
bool isRubberBand = false;
bool IsClicked(CRect r, int x, int y);

void select(HWND hWnd, CRect r);
void deselect(HWND hWnd, CRect r);
void DrawRubberBand(HWND hWnd);
void MoveFromTo(HDC hdc, CRect &rectSelected, POINTS anchor, POINTS now);

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
CRect add;
static CRect rectSelected;
TCHAR s[100] = L"";
HDC             hdc;
static POINTS   anchor;

switch (message)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId)
    {
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
break;

case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
    for (auto& rc : vRect)
    {
        Rectangle(hdc,
            rc.left,
            rc.top,
            rc.right,
            rc.bottom
        );
    }
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
}
break;

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{
    LeftButtonDown.x = LOWORD(lParam); //Start point
    LeftButtonDown.y = HIWORD(lParam);

    isRubberBand = true;

    ptCurrent.x = LOWORD(lParam); //current point
    ptCurrent.y = HIWORD(lParam);

    DrawRubberBand(hWnd); //draw the rect
}
break;

case WM_LBUTTONUP: // adding to a vector
{
    if (!isRubberBand)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    isRubberBand = false;

    //InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    add.SetRect(LeftButtonDown.x, LeftButtonDown.y, ptCurrent.x, ptCurrent.y); //setting the coords of the rect
    vRect.push_back(add); //add the rect
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
}
break;

case WM_MOUSEMOVE:

    if (wParam & MK_LBUTTON) //drawing the rectangle
    {
        hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        if (!isRubberBand)
        {
            break;
        }
        DrawRubberBand(hWnd);

        ptCurrent.x = LOWORD(lParam);
        ptCurrent.y = HIWORD(lParam);

        DrawRubberBand(hWnd);

    }
    if (wParam & MK_RBUTTON) //dragging the rectangle
    {
        hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        POINTS now = MAKEPOINTS(lParam);
        if (PtInRect(&rectSelected, POINT{ now.x,now.y }))
        {
            SetROP2(hdc, R2_NOTXORPEN);
            MoveFromTo(hdc, rectSelected, anchor, now);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            anchor = MAKEPOINTS(lParam);
        }

        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    }
    break;

case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
{
    bool isFind = false;
    int x{ LOWORD(lParam) }, y{ HIWORD(lParam) };
    for (auto& rc : vRect)
    {
        if (!isFind && IsClicked(rc, x, y))
        {
            select(hWnd, rc);
            rectSelected = rc;
            anchor = MAKEPOINTS(lParam);
            isFind = TRUE;
        }
        else {
            deselect(hWnd, rc);
        }
    }
    //select-deselect
}
break;
case WM_RBUTTONUP:
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}


bool IsClicked(CRect r, int x, int y)
{
    POINT pt{ x, y };
return (bool)PtInRect(&r, pt);
}
void select(HWND hWnd, CRect r) {
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
HPEN selectPen = CreatePen(PS_DOT, 0, RGB(255, 0, 0));
SelectObject(hdc, selectPen);
Rectangle(hdc, r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom);
DeleteObject(selectPen);
}
void deselect(HWND hWnd, CRect r) {
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
Rectangle(hdc, r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom);
}

void DrawRubberBand(HWND hWnd) {
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);

SetROP2(hdc, R2_NOT);
SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
Rectangle(hdc,
    LeftButtonDown.x,
    LeftButtonDown.y,
    ptCurrent.x,
    ptCurrent.y
);
ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
}
void MoveFromTo(HDC hdc, CRect &rectSelected, POINTS anchor, POINTS now)
{
Rectangle(hdc, rectSelected.left, rectSelected.top, rectSelected.right, rectSelected.bottom);
for (auto it = vRect.begin();it != vRect.end();it++)
{
    if (*it == rectSelected)
    {
        vRect.erase(it);
        break;
    }
}
rectSelected.left = rectSelected.left + now.x - anchor.x; //x
rectSelected.top = rectSelected.top + now.y - anchor.y;    //y
rectSelected.right = rectSelected.right + now.x - anchor.x; //x
rectSelected.bottom = rectSelected.bottom + now.y - anchor.y; //y
Rectangle(hdc, rectSelected.left, rectSelected.top, rectSelected.right, rectSelected.bottom);
vRect.push_back(rectSelected);
}
```

Comment: All drawing should be done in response to WM_PAINT. Look for an example that does (simple) drawing and learn from that.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the `rubber-banding` is an exception of that rule, for efficiency reasons (as I understand it)

Comment: @vla Convenience, rather than efficiency. The rubber band is rendered using raster operations, that need to be canceled out on every change. The `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message is the message that has access to most of the required state information. It's no less efficient to have the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message handler store state information and have the `WM_PAINT` message handle the rest. It just implies having state information bleed out into unrelated regions of code.

Comment: Anyway, *"it doesn't work"* is not a problem statement. Please see [ask]. Though not immediately relevant, `CRect` is not a type exposed by the Windows API. Are you using some framework? If so, which one?

Comment: The [`Rectangle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rectangle) function "*draws a rectangle. The rectangle is outlined by using the current pen **and filled by using the current brush**.*" But you are not selecting any colored brushes into the `HDC`s you are drawing on.  And `DrawRubberBand()` is actually using `NULL_BRUSH`.  Look at `CreateSolidBrush()` and related functions.

Comment: Refer to [`Creating Colored Pens and Brushes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/creating-colored-pens-and-brushes)

Comment: You can look at how MFC does that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/crecttracker-class?view=msvc-160.

Or may be you can just use MFC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you're primarily missing two things:

1. where you draw your rectangles, you aren't creating and selecting a brush, so the default brush is being used to fill your rectangles.
2. Where you handle WM_LBUTTONUP, you're not invalidating the rectangle after you add it to your vector of rectangles to draw. So it doesn't get drawn (until you do something that forces it to be re-drawn like minimizing and restoring it).

That's pretty much all you're missing through.

So at the end of your WM_LBUTTONUP handler, you can replace your call to `UpdateWindow`, (which isn't necessary here) with a call to `InvalidateRect`, something like this: `InvalidateRect(hWnd, add, true);`. Note that this only invalidates the rectangle that we just drew (where your other code passes NULL for the invalid rectangle, so it invalidates everything). Only invalidating the part that's really invalid can improve efficiency (somewhat).

And in your WM_PAINT handler, you want code something like this:

```cpp
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    // For the moment, I'm just hard-coding a fairly bright red fill:
    HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(192, 0, 0));
    HBRUSH original = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(hdc, brush);

    // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
    for (auto& rc : vRect)
    {
        Rectangle(hdc,
            rc.left,
            rc.top,
            rc.right,
            rc.bottom
        );
    }
    // restore original brush before releasing the DC:
    SelectObject(hdc, original);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    // And destroy the brush:
    DeleteObject(brush);
}
break;
```